# RSpec - How to run FactoryGirl.create before each test except for one in a describe block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have RSpec tests and within one describe block I use FactoryGirl to create a model before (:each) test. For one test within my describe block I would like to create a Factory with different attributes. Any ideas how this is best done?

Answer (score 2):

You could create the object in before(:each) and change the attribute for the same object in your test that needs it

```
describe "test" do
  before(:each) do
   @model = FactoryGirl.create(:model)
  end

  it "should do something" do
    @model.update_attribute(:attribute, :value)
  end
end
```

Another way:

```
   describe "test" do
      before(:each) do
       @model = FactoryGirl.create(:model)
      end

      it "should do something" do
        model1 = FactoryGirl.create(:model, :attribute1 => "value")
      end
    end
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. However, I actually need these attributes to be updated before FactoryGirl object is created. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Create another object with the attributes that you need inside the test that needs it. See edit